# Joomla Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM

Tags: php, joomla2.5

I have building a web site but i have a error code and i couldnt fould a fix it

Error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM in /home/eneskura/public_html/administrator/components/com_tz_portfolio/helpers/tz_portfolio.php on line 42

line 42-

```
$class::addEntry(JText::('COM_TZ_PORTFOLIO_SUBMENU_GROUP_FIELDS'), 'index.php?option=com_tz_portfolio&view=fieldsgroup', $vName == 'fieldsgroup');
```

how i can i fix it?

Site: eneskuray.com php 5.2.17 litespeed

full php

```
<?php

// No direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

class TZ_PortfolioHelper
{
    public static $extension = 'com_content';

    /**
     * Configure the Linkbar.
     *
     * @param   string  $vName  The name of the active view.
     *
     * @return  void
     * @since   1.6
     */
    public static function addSubmenu($vName)
    {
        $class  = 'JHtmlSidebar';
        if(!COM_TZ_PORTFOLIO_JVERSION_COMPARE){
            $class  = 'JSubMenuHelper';
        }

       $class::addEntry( JText::_('COM_TZ_PORTFOLIO_SUBMENU_GROUP_FIELDS'), 'index.php?option=com_tz_portfolio&view=fieldsgroup', $vName == 'fieldsgroup');
        $class::addEntry(
            JText::_('COM_TZ_PORTFOLIO_SUBMENU_FIELDS'),
            'index.php?option=com_tz_portfolio&view=fields',
            $vName == 'fields'
        );
        $class::addEntry(
            JText::_('COM_TZ_PORTFOLIO_SUBMENU_CATEGORIES'),
            'index.php?option=com_tz_portfolio&view=categories',
            $vName == 'categories');
        $class::addEntry(
            JText::_('COM_TZ_PORTFOLIO_SUBMENU_ARTICLES'),
            'index.php?option=com_tz_portfolio&view=articles',
            $vName == 'articles'
        );
        $class::addEntry(
            JText::_('COM_TZ_PORTFOLIO_SUBMENU_FEATURED_ARTICLES'),
            'index.php?option=com_tz_portfolio&view=featured',
            $vName == 'featured'
        );
        $class::addEntry(
            JText::_('COM_TZ_PORTFOLIO_SUBMENU_TAGS'),
            'index.php?option=com_tz_portfolio&view=tags',
            $vName == 'tags');
        $class::addEntry(
            JText::_('COM_TZ_PORTFOLIO_SUBMENU_USERS'),
            'index.php?option=com_tz_portfolio&view=users',
            $vName == 'users');
    }

    /**
     * Gets a list of the actions that can be performed.
     *
     * @param   int     The category ID.
     * @param   int     The article ID.
     *
     * @return  JObject
     * @since   1.6
     */
    public static function getActions($categoryId = 0, $articleId = 0)
    {
        $user   = JFactory::getUser();
        $result = new JObject;

        if (empty($articleId) && empty($categoryId)) {
            $assetName = 'com_tz_portfolio';
        }
        elseif (empty($articleId)) {
            $assetName = 'com_tz_portfolio.category.'.(int) $categoryId;
        }
        else {
            $assetName = 'com_tz_portfolio.article.'.(int) $articleId;
        }

        $actions = array(
            'core.admin', 'core.manage', 'core.create', 'core.edit', 'core.edit.own', 'core.edit.state', 'core.delete'
        );

        foreach ($actions as $action) {
            $result->set($action,   $user->authorise($action, $assetName));
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
    * Applies the content tag filters to arbitrary text as per settings for current user group
    * @param text The string to filter
    * @return string The filtered string
    */
    public static function filterText($text)
    {
        // Filter settings
        $config     = JComponentHelper::getParams('com_config');
        $user       = JFactory::getUser();
        $userGroups = JAccess::getGroupsByUser($user->get('id'));

        $filters = $config->get('filters');

        $blackListTags          = array();
        $blackListAttributes    = array();

        $customListTags         = array();
        $customListAttributes   = array();

        $whiteListTags          = array();
        $whiteListAttributes    = array();

        $noHtml             = false;
        $whiteList          = false;
        $blackList          = false;
        $customList         = false;
        $unfiltered         = false;

        // Cycle through each of the user groups the user is in.
        // Remember they are included in the Public group as well.
        foreach ($userGroups as $groupId)
        {
            // May have added a group but not saved the filters.
            if (!isset($filters->$groupId)) {
                continue;
            }

            // Each group the user is in could have different filtering properties.
            $filterData = $filters->$groupId;
            $filterType = strtoupper($filterData->filter_type);

            if ($filterType == 'NH') {
                // Maximum HTML filtering.
                $noHtml = true;
            }
            elseif ($filterType == 'NONE') {
                // No HTML filtering.
                $unfiltered = true;
            }
            else {
                // Black, white or custom list.
                // Preprocess the tags and attributes.
                $tags           = explode(',', $filterData->filter_tags);
                $attributes     = explode(',', $filterData->filter_attributes);
                $tempTags       = array();
                $tempAttributes = array();

                foreach ($tags as $tag)
                {
                    $tag = trim($tag);

                    if ($tag) {
                        $tempTags[] = $tag;
                    }
                }

                foreach ($attributes as $attribute)
                {
                    $attribute = trim($attribute);

                    if ($attribute) {
                        $tempAttributes[] = $attribute;
                    }
                }

                // Collect the black or white list tags and attributes.
                // Each lists is cummulative.
                if ($filterType == 'BL') {
                    $blackList              = true;
                    $blackListTags          = array_merge($blackListTags, $tempTags);
                    $blackListAttributes    = array_merge($blackListAttributes, $tempAttributes);
                }
                elseif ($filterType == 'CBL') {
                    // Only set to true if Tags or Attributes were added
                    if ($tempTags || $tempAttributes) {
                        $customList             = true;
                        $customListTags         = array_merge($customListTags, $tempTags);
                        $customListAttributes   = array_merge($customListAttributes, $tempAttributes);
                    }
                }
                elseif ($filterType == 'WL') {
                    $whiteList              = true;
                    $whiteListTags          = array_merge($whiteListTags, $tempTags);
                    $whiteListAttributes    = array_merge($whiteListAttributes, $tempAttributes);
                }
            }
        }

        // Remove duplicates before processing (because the black list uses both sets of arrays).
        $blackListTags          = array_unique($blackListTags);
        $blackListAttributes    = array_unique($blackListAttributes);
        $customListTags         = array_unique($customListTags);
        $customListAttributes   = array_unique($customListAttributes);
        $whiteListTags          = array_unique($whiteListTags);
        $whiteListAttributes    = array_unique($whiteListAttributes);

        // Unfiltered assumes first priority.
        if ($unfiltered) {
            // Dont apply filtering.
        }
        else {
            // Custom blacklist precedes Default blacklist
            if ($customList) {
                $filter = JFilterInput::getInstance(array(), array(), 1, 1);

                // Override filter's default blacklist tags and attributes
                if ($customListTags) {
                    $filter->tagBlacklist = $customListTags;
                }
                if ($customListAttributes) {
                    $filter->attrBlacklist = $customListAttributes;
                }
            }
            // Black lists take third precedence.
            elseif ($blackList) {
                // Remove the white-listed attributes from the black-list.
                $filter = JFilterInput::getInstance(
                    array_diff($blackListTags, $whiteListTags),             // blacklisted tags
                    array_diff($blackListAttributes, $whiteListAttributes), // blacklisted attributes
                    1,                                                      // blacklist tags
                    1                                                       // blacklist attributes
                );
                // Remove white listed tags from filter's default blacklist
                if ($whiteListTags) {
                    $filter->tagBlacklist = array_diff($filter->tagBlacklist, $whiteListTags);
                }
                // Remove white listed attributes from filter's default blacklist
                if ($whiteListAttributes) {
                    $filter->attrBlacklist = array_diff($filter->attrBlacklist);
                }

            }
            // White lists take fourth precedence.
            elseif ($whiteList) {
                $filter = JFilterInput::getInstance($whiteListTags, $whiteListAttributes, 0, 0, 0);  // turn off xss auto clean
            }
            // No HTML takes last place.
            else {
                $filter = JFilterInput::getInstance();
            }

            $text = $filter->clean($text, 'html');
        }

        return $text;
    }
}
```

ATTETION : some texts deleted for privacy.

Comment: `JText::(` is not calling a method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [scope resolution operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php) (::) can only be used on a class referenced using a variable from PHP 5.3 -- you're using 5.2.

You'd have to do `JHtmlSidebar::addEntry` or `JSubMenuHelper::addEntry`; you can't do `$class::addEntry`.

Answer (score 2):

`JText::('COM_TZ_PORTFOLIO_SUBMENU_GROUP_FIELDS')` is not calling a method. It should be:

```
JText::_('COM_TZ_PORTFOLIO_SUBMENU_GROUP_FIELDS')
```

See [`JText`](http://docs.joomla.org/JText/).

Answer (score 2):

`T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM` refers to the two colons in a row like this `::`.  Looking at your code sample:

```
$class::addEntry( JText::('COM_TZ_PORTFOLIO_SUBMENU_GROUP_FIELDS'), 'index.php?option=com_tz_portfolio&view=fieldsgroup', $vName == 'fieldsgroup');
```

I believe the issue is with `JText::(`. As per [Joomla documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/JText/) that should be formatted with an underscore so it is `JText::_(` so your code would be:

```
$class::addEntry( JText::_('COM_TZ_PORTFOLIO_SUBMENU_GROUP_FIELDS'), 'index.php?option=com_tz_portfolio&view=fieldsgroup', $vName == 'fieldsgroup');
```

Not 100% clear on Joomla internals, but that underscore (`_`) is actually a function/method of some sort within the `JText` class. So when you were calling it as `JText::(` PHP choked because it had no idea what you were trying to do with `JText`.  By adding that underscore (`_`), it will now actually call a function within a class & do what it has to do.

Comment: sorry it didnt work. added full php.

Comment: full php file. tz_portfolio.php